# url cutoff by link module or pagepeeker formatter issue in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, module

I have drupal 7 question that may involve some php help. I have created an rss feed from google alerts that I am mapping into fields. I have had success mapping into all the fields except the link module field where I have put a field formatter that creates a pagepeeker screenshot by attaching the appropriate url server query to the feeds url. Feeds is doing its job by taking the Item URL (link) and putting it into the field correctly. I am having an issue with with either pagepeeker or link module because below keeps happening.

To recap-

Google Alert feed -> Link module field -> pagepeeker screenshot formatter

here's the error

The url that google alerts provides is

http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&q=http://www.beautyjunkiesunite.com/WP/2012/05/30/whats-new-anastasia-beverly-hills-lash-genius/&ct=ga&cad=CAcQARgAIAEoATAAOABA3t-Y_gRIAlgBYgVlbi1VUw&cd=F7w9TwL-6ao&usg=AFQjCNG2rbJCENvRR2_k6pL9RntjP66Rvg

When the link is displayed I get :

http://pagepeeker.com/thumbs.php?size=m&url=www.google.com/url

Its cutting the url at url and not getting the rest of the url.

Here's the code that pagepeeker uses to parse the url ?

```
<?php

function _pagepeeker_format_url($url, $domain_only = FALSE) {
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
return FALSE;
}

// try to parse the url
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
if (!empty($parsed_url)) {
  $host = (!empty($parsed_url['host'])) ? $parsed_url['host'] : '';
  $port = (!empty($parsed_url['port'])) ? ':' . $parsed_url['port'] : '';
  $path = (!empty($parsed_url['path'])) ? $parsed_url['path'] : '';
  $query = (!empty($parsed_url['query'])) ? '?' . $parsed_url['query'] : '';
  $fragment = (!empty($parsed_url['fragment'])) ? '#' . $parsed_url['fragment'] : '';

if ($domain_only) {
  return $host . $port;
}
else {
  return $host . $port . $path . $query . $fragment;
}
}

return FALSE;
}
```

Could this be the problem?

Please let me know I can clarify in any way.

What I need is for the entire url to get processed and not just the truncated one

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen a very similar question here at SO or drupal SO page but couldn't find it so I'm writing "my way" answer again here.

```
<?php


function _pagepeeker_format_url($url, $domain_only = FALSE) {
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
return FALSE;
}

//$url = 'http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&q=http://www.beautyjunkiesunite.com/WP/2012/05/30/whats-new-anastasia-beverly-hills-lash-genius/&ct=ga&cad=CAcQARgAIAEoATAAOABA3t-Y_gRIAlgBYgVlbi1VUw&cd=F7w9TwL-6ao&usg=AFQjCNG2rbJCENvRR2_k6pL9RntjP66Rvg';
// Now we use parse_url to split the url to an array with url parts.
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
// $parsed_url['query'] is 'sa=X&q=http://www.beautyjunkiesunite.com/WP/2012/05/30/whats-new-anastasia-beverly-hills-lash-genius/&ct=ga&cad=CAcQARgAIAEoATAAOABA3t-Y_gRIAlgBYgVlbi1VUw&cd=F7w9TwL-6ao&usg=AFQjCNG2rbJCENvRR2_k6pL9RntjP66Rvg'
// ";" can also be used to separate params. But & is the usual one so using it.
$queryParts = explode('&', $parsed_url['query']);

    $params = array();
    foreach ($queryParts as $param) {
        $item = explode('=', $param);
        // sa = X, etc.
        $params[$item[0]] = $item[1];
    }
//$params is now an array with query parts.
// $params['sa'] = 'X' , q = 'http://www.beautyjunkiesunite.com/WP/2012/05/30/whats-new-anastasia-beverly-hills-lash-genius', etc.

if ($domain_only){
$new_url_parsts = parse_url($params['q']);
return $new_url_parts['host'];
}
else{
return $params['q'];
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks this is a huge help ! thanks ! I noticed that theres param and params Is that suppose to be like that also I am getting an unexpected $end error when I add it but then if I add return FALSE; after return $params['q'] the error is gone but throws a new error that Notice: Undefined index: q in _pagepeeker_format_url() this is good start thanks –

Comment: OMG I'm sorry
Replace $parsed_url = parse_url('$url');
 with $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
(edited answer)

Comment: Hi Thanks so much!! I made the change but its still errors on these items Notice: Undefined index: q in _pagepeeker_format_url(), Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in _pagepeeker_format_url(), Notice: Undefined index: query in _pagepeeker_format_url(). Is there a way to define these items as the module is not producing any urls at all now? I googled some of this and it says that maybe isset could work something like or could it be that this new code is not declared in the other parts of the module or is it exclusive to this function? thanks again for all your help your awesome!!

Comment: If the formatter is receiving the URL correctly, you shouldn't see any notices or errors. 
TO check that out, download and try: http://pastebin.com/zKnUbDXg
It's actually the same as above, but with error reporting on setting and a sample URL.

Comment: Okay great i will try that for sure. Thanks again for all your help. Here is a screenshot of the error I am receiving. http://c626951.r51.cf2.rackcdn.com/ss.png

Comment: I added the error reporting and its still showing those same errors here is a screen shot http://c626951.r51.cf2.rackcdn.com/ss2.png Here is the entire module code too http://pastebin.com/uM4pbtBQ once again thanks very much for all your help I think that there's something weird with new code integrated into the whole module

Comment: Actually i thought you'd download the the pastebin file as a php file (not as a module) and will upload it. When you execute it (just calling the file directly), you will see that the url you needed. 
That was just to make sure the function itself works if it receives the information correctly. (it worked at my end on php 5.3)

May be we will need to figure out if $url is a valid URL, it has the "q" param and is not empty. Link field can usually validate it.

Comment: I did try that and yes you are correct the function does work as a stand alone. I agree I think that if $url is a valid url it should pass and if it is a google alert feed url it should be parsed with the function you wrote. Cause its really only the google alert feed urls that have this issue I am having, other urls work just fine. and once again your awesome!